# The softlink create by me can NOT be access by others

Tags: permissions, ln

I make a folder "target" in my home and I change its mode to 777 (drwxrwxrwx), I create a softlink in /tmp folder,in /tmp folder.

```
    ln -s /home/[myusername]/target target
```

I can read,write to the softlink target(lrwxrwxrwx) , but others can NOT access this softlink .why?

Answer (score 0):

the /tmp folder permission in linux system is 'drwxrwxrwt', the last is 't'.
this permission can not access other's folder.

I create the a softlink by root user. solve it .